# ListView inside a ListView Template not allowing me to bind to the parents ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, templatebinding

So I am trying to build a cool ListView that has a "CheckAll" button that allows me to check all of the items in the list view. Then I can reuse this control in several places. So I have a ControlTemplate where I am trying to bind a new ListView's ItemsSource property to the parent controls ItemsSource property. It let's me define it if I set the TargetType="ListView" but then I get an XML Parse Exception that it can't use it.

```
<ListView x:Class="CheckAllBox.CheckAllListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         BorderThickness=".5" BorderBrush="Gray">
    <ListView.Resources>

    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Margin="0" Padding="2" Background="White">
                        <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Content="Check All" Click="CheckAllChecked" BorderBrush="Gray" IsChecked="{Binding IsAllChecked}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle Height="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <ListView Name="CompleteList" Grid.Row="2" Background="White" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Checked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled}">
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                </CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListView.Template>
</ListView>
```

My view is binding to a Collection of:

```
    public interface ICheckListItem
    {
        bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        bool? IsSelected { get; set; }

        string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And my test data looks like:

```
    public List<myCollectionItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<myCollectionItem>
    {
        new myCollectionItem { IsEnabled = false, IsSelected = true, Name = "Object 1" },
        new myCollectionItem { IsEnabled = false, IsSelected = true, Name = "Object 1" },
        new myCollectionItem { IsEnabled = false, IsSelected = true, Name = "Object 1" },
    };
```

So my Error is on the line that says:

```
<ListView Name="CompleteList" Grid.Row="2" Background="White" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
```

Comment: Why not use an `ItemsPresenter`? That's what they're for.

Comment: Why not indeed... that fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than doing that with a nested `ListView`, the "correct" way that all the standard WPF items control templates use is an `ItemsPresenter`.

Comment: So I knew that about item presenters... but I was just doing something dumb. /sigh Anyways I would vote for your answer... but I've never gotten more than 1 rep, lol. Thanks again.